# How change DateTime format

Tags: hibernate, date, datetime, timestamp

I want to store DateTime in database by hibernate so It should be in this format
2012-10-1T11:50:50 but I want user to enter this format 2012-10-1 50:50:50  in textbox or by datebicker,How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use two SimpleDateFormat,like below.

```
            SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = input.parse("2012-10-01 10:50:50");
            String result = output.format(date);
            System.out.println(result);
```